# InnoSetup and NSSM Exit code 5

Tags: node.js, windows, service, inno-setup, nssm

I have an application installer in node-js platform, currently developing an installer with Inno Setup and NSSM (The application should run as a service).

The thing is when NSSM tries to register the service (The device is a Windows 8.1 32 bits Enterprise running over a tablet PC), NSSM fails with Exit code 5.

I couldn't find anything more usefull than access denied and no help in the matter. Tried a lot of stuff, like changing the folders, the names, the users, every time, it fails.

Inno script looks like this:

```
; Add System Service Filename: "{app}\{#NSSM}";
Parameters: "install {#MyAppShortName} {app}\winstart-server.bat";
Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser;
Filename: "{app}\{#NSSM}";
Parameters: "set {#MyAppShortName} AppStdin {app}\{#MyAppShortName}.log";
Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser; 
Filename: "{app}\{#NSSM}";
Parameters: "set {#MyAppShortName} AppStdout {app}\{#MyAppShortName}.log";
Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser; 
Filename: "{app}\{#NSSM}";
Parameters: "set {#MyAppShortName} AppStderr {app}\{#MyAppShortName}.log";
Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser; 
Filename: "{app}\{#NSSM}";
Parameters: "set {#MyAppShortName} AppRotateFiles 1";
Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser;
Filename: "{sys}\net.exe";
Parameters: "start {#MyAppShortName}";
Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser;
```

And the log prompts from the installer when is run looks like this:

```
2015-09-07 20:41:22.616   -- Run entry --
2015-09-07 20:41:22.616   Run as: Current user
2015-09-07 20:41:22.616   Type: Exec
2015-09-07 20:41:22.616   Filename: C:\Monitor\nssm.exe
2015-09-07 20:41:22.616   Parameters: install Monitor C:\Monitor\winstart-server.bat
2015-09-07 20:41:24.262   Process exit code: 5
2015-09-07 20:41:24.262   -- Run entry --
2015-09-07 20:41:24.262   Run as: Current user
2015-09-07 20:41:24.262   Type: Exec
2015-09-07 20:41:24.262   Filename: C:\Monitor\nssm.exe
2015-09-07 20:41:24.262   Parameters: set Monitor AppStdin C:\Monitor\Monitor.log
2015-09-07 20:41:24.299   Process exit code: 3
2015-09-07 20:41:24.299   -- Run entry --
2015-09-07 20:41:24.299   Run as: Current user
2015-09-07 20:41:24.299   Type: Exec
2015-09-07 20:41:24.299   Filename: C:\Monitor\nssm.exe
2015-09-07 20:41:24.299   Parameters: set Monitor AppStdout C:\Monitor\Monitor.log
2015-09-07 20:41:24.365   Process exit code: 3
2015-09-07 20:41:24.365   -- Run entry --
2015-09-07 20:41:24.365   Run as: Current user
2015-09-07 20:41:24.365   Type: Exec
2015-09-07 20:41:24.365   Filename: C:\Monitor\nssm.exe
2015-09-07 20:41:24.365   Parameters: set Monitor AppStderr C:\Monitor\Monitor.log
2015-09-07 20:41:24.415   Process exit code: 3
2015-09-07 20:41:24.415   -- Run entry --
2015-09-07 20:41:24.415   Run as: Current user
2015-09-07 20:41:24.415   Type: Exec
2015-09-07 20:41:24.415   Filename: C:\Monitor\nssm.exe
2015-09-07 20:41:24.415   Parameters: set Monitor AppRotateFiles 1
2015-09-07 20:41:24.458   Process exit code: 3
```

As you can see, the first taks fails with 5 and then the others prompt a 3 because the service was not registered.

Any clues? Thank you very much on advance.

Comment: Are you running the installer as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I think the permissions are ok. Also tried changing the user to poweruser.

Comment: Please give this a try on the CLI `C:\Monitor\nssm.exe install MyMonitorService C:\Monitor\winstart-server.bat` - just for testing the service installation under a different name and outside of inno.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that windows already has a service called "Monitor" (sys/DRIVERS/monitor). Try changing the name of your service for something else!